# What replaced WM_BNCLICKED

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Using this [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/589/A-Beginners-Guide-to-Dialog-Based-Applications-Par) and translating on the fly to VS2019 IDE. Got to step of "Adding Message Handlers for the Controls" and trying to locate BNCLICKED in Class Wizard Messages tab. I see many other WM_XXXBUTTON... messages but no BNCLICKED. What replaces BNCLICKED?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WM_XXXBUTTON...` message you refer to (such as `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`) are messages sent when a *mouse* button does something. For buttons in dialog boxes (and other UI components), the 'message' sent is [**`BN_CLICKED`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bn-clicked) (note the underscore). Technically, this is a *notification code* rather than a message in its own right, and is sent as the high word of the `wParam` of a [`WM_COMMAND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/menurc/wm-command) message.

Comment: Thank you Adrian. I spent more time "clicking around" in the IDE and found I had to go to the Command tab and find my button control and once I chose that I found the BN_CLICKED notification